# Exporting Workflows | Orchard CMS 1.9.1 to Orchard CMS 1.7

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7, orchard-modules

I have few workflows created in Orchard 1.9.1 . When exporting items from 1.9.1, there doesn't seems any option/checkbox to export the WorkFlows at Export/Import Screen: http://localhost:30321/Admin/ImportExport/Export

How can I export workflows from 1.9.1 to 1.7.1 ? Is it possible ?

Comment: You should see the option to export Workflows as a custom export step at the bottom of the Export screen. Whether they will export from 1.9.1 to 1.7.1 I don't know. Why, may I ask, are you moving from 1.9.1 to 1.7.1? Seems a strange thing to be doing.

Comment: My mistake. I thought it will execute some Workflow activity when i start the Export process. Isn't the desc Text confusing: " Choose the custom steps to execute in the export file:"  Request you to post your comment as answer if possible

Comment: Agree , its strange. When we started out with Orchard, we tested and implemented using the latest version 1.9.1. Later on we were told that the Servers were actual website will be hosted have .Net 4.0 only , NOT .NET 4.5. So the latest orchard 1.7 is the one works with .NET 4.0

Comment: Ah I see, that sucks. And yes, the text is very confusing, I believe it has been brought up before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should see the option to export Workflows as a custom export step at the bottom of the Export screen.